# Count the items of a List according to their status

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My question is simple, but I can't find a solution in my search.
Well, I have here these Classes and Lists:

```
public class Table
{
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public List<Request> Requests { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public List<Table> Tables = new List<Table>();
```

The tables can have two status: `Unoccupied` and `Occupied`. What I need is to count all the tables presents in the Table List and separate them according to Status, but I don't know how to do this. For example, I have two tables with their status occupied and three tables with their status unoccupied. I need the output like: `You have 2 tables occupied and 3 tables unoccupied`. I think I need to use a `while` loop, but I don't know how to count separate.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `GroupBy`

```
var results = Tables.GroupBy(t => t.Status)
    .Select(g => new
        {
            Status = g.Key, 
            Count = g.Count()
         });

foreach(var item in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} tables of status {1}", item.Count, item.Status);
}
```

Note that this will only give you statuses that have at least one table, so if a status has none and you need that as well you can adjust to the following.

```
var results = Tables.GroupBy(t => t.Status)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

foreach(var status in new[] {"Unoccupied", "Occupied"})
{
    int count;
    results.TryGetValue(status, out count);
    Console.WriteLine("You have {0} tables of status {1}", count, status);
}
```

Also you might want to consider creating an `enum` for the `Status` if it should only be one of two values.

```
public enum TableStatus
{
    Unoccupied,
    Occupied
}
```

Comment: @Dyan, I missed the part about getting `Count`, IMO, this answer is much better and if I were you, I would have accepted this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ like:

```
List<Table> UnoccupiedTables = Tables.Where(r=> r.Status == "Unoccupied")
                                     .ToList();

List<Table> OccupiedTables = Tables.Where(r=> r.Status == "Occupied")
                                     .ToList();
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then you can replace you can use `String.Equals` like:

```
String.Equals(r.Status, "Occupied", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

I missed the part of *getting count*. You can use `GroupBy` as mentioned in the other answer, or you can get count for each item like:

```
int CountOfUnoccupiedTables = Tables.Count(r=> r.Status == "Unoccupied");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified a bit your solution. I'm using `var OccupiedTables = Tables.Where(r => r.Status == "Occupied").Count();` and worked great. Thank you!

Comment: @Dyan, that or `Tables.Count(r=> r.Status == "Occupied");`, You are welcome